# could not find Wordnet dictionary error

Tags: r, wordnet

I'm having trouble running [wordnet in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordnet/index.html). I loaded it into the library initially, but it didn't work. The error looked like this:

```
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
```

So, I added this line: `Sys.setenv(WNHOME = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\2.1")`
and then was able to use the library function to load it. I don't understand this line or error message at all, but it seems to fix this problem.

However, whenever I try to use the package, it won't work. For example, I entered:

```
filter <- getTermFilter("ExactMatchFilter", "hot", TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("ADJECTIVE", 1, filter)
```

and got the following error message after the second line:

```
Error in getDict() : could not find Wordnet dictionary
```

I don't understand what this means. Do I have to set a dictionary? How would I do this, and to what should I set it? Otherwise, how do I get rid of this error message?

Thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The R wordnet package is designed for Wordnet 3.0, and you seem to be using 2.1, so I imagine that would be the problem.

As a second guess, try installing Wordnet in a path with no spaces in it. E.g. `c:\\data\\wordnet`

By the way, instead of using `Sys.setenv()` to set an environment variable, it appears you could instead do `setDict("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\3.0")` before the call to `initDict()`, or even simply give that path as the optional parameter to `initDict()`.