# cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory

Tags: r, wordnet

on MAC OSX

```
synonyms("company", "NOUN")
Error in getDict() : could not find Wordnet dictionary
```

I was going to use the "setDict" function to setup the directory but there is no "dict" directory in the wordnet path

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/wordnet
```

Comment: One of the first thing before posting question is to search SO to see if someone has already answered similar question. Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331985/could-not-find-wordnet-dictionary-error) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129073/wordnet-getdict-could-not-find-wordnet-dictionary) . If does not answer kindly edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The point  is that I am using "MAC OSX" and DO NOT SEE the "dict" directory as part of the wordnet package. Unless I have missed something here.  When attempting to set the directory I get the following. cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to get wordnet to work from R.

- First is installing wordnet and required JDK on the OS.
- Second part is to install wordnet package on R. Here are the steps that worked.

### Steps from Ubuntu software center

Step 1: Install "wordnet"
Step 2: Install "Java Development kit"
Step 3: GNU R low-level interface to Java run "r-cran-rjava"
Step 4: To get R and Java to work together run "sudo R CMD javareconf"
Step 5: Do a find to locate where wordnet is installed, I found it here "/usr/bin/wordnet"

### Steps on R console

Step 1: `Sys.setenv(WNHOME = "/usr/bin/wordnet")`
Step 2: `install.packages("wordnet")`
Step 3: `library(wordnet)`
Step 4: `path <- file.path("usr", "share", "dict")`
Step 5: `setDict(path)`

And finaly testing wordnet using the synonyms function

```
> synonyms("man", "NOUN")
[1] "adult male"            "gentleman"             "gentleman's gentleman"
[4] "homo"                  "human"                 "human being"         
[7] "human beings"          "humanity"              "humankind"           
[10] "human race"            "humans"                "Isle of Man"         
[13] "man"                   "Man"                   "mankind"             
[16] "military man"          "military personnel"    "piece"               
[19] "serviceman"            "valet"                 "valet de chambre"    
[22] "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue, here is how I solved that issue. I assume you have already installed the R wordnet package. This solution works for mac os 10.9.5:

Download WordNet from the Princeton homepage
    http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WordNet-3.0.tar.gz

Unzip it and go to the directory

```
cd .../WordNet-3.0
```

Add this line to src/stubs.c before the #include lines

```
#define USE_INTERP_RESULT 1
```

you may have to give yourself the right to modify this file

```
chmod u+rw stubs.c
```

Go back to the WordNet directory and configure WordNet

```
cd ...
./configure
```

Make and install the package

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

In my case WordNet was installed in /usr/local

Hence I just had to call the dictionary in R using:

```
setDict("/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/")
```